# Merging mesh assemblies to create Augmented Reality files. How to reduce file size?

Tags: modeling

Semi-Noob here.

I have created several Blender assemblies with tons of individual objects, textures, decals, etc. and they look great. (These were originally Fusion assemblies.) Now I have to create AR files and want to reduce the file size dramatically.

I'm thinking that there must be a way to create one solid mesh from all of this and bake on the textures. I don't want to include any of the internal objects that won't be seen. The resulting file would just be outer surface.

Are there tools in Blender to help remove unseen objects? Or am I making this too complicated?

Thanks.